# When are you supposed to eta-reduce?

Tags: algorithms, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, normal-forms, term-rewriting

Wikipedia lists the [following algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_normal_form#Reduction_strategies) for normalizing a lambda calculus term $t$:

- If $t$ is not in head normal form, beta reduce the beta redex in the head position to get $t'$. Then normalize $t'$ to get $t''$. $t''$ is the normal form of $t$.
- If $t$ is in head normal form, normalize each of its subterms to get $t'$. $t'$ is the normal form of $t$.

The implied base case is if $t$ is in head normal form but has no subterms, in which case it is in normal form already. If $t$ has a normal form, the above algorithm is guaranteed to find it.

The problem I'm having is that it does not seem that the algorithm ever eta-reduces.

For example given the algorithm normalizes $\lambda y.\lambda x.y x$ to itself (since it is already in head normal form, and $x$ is also in head normal form). It should normalize to $\lambda y. y$ though.

It seems apparent that you need to add eta-reduction steps at *some point*. The problem is I'm not sure where to put them and preserve the property that the algorithm is guaranteed to find the normal form.

When and where do you eta-reduce to achieve this?

Comment: The Wikipedia page is talking about *beta* normal form. $\lambda y.\lambda x.yx$ is in beta normal form. There are no beta redexes anywhere. It also fits the explicit description of what normal forms look like given on that page. It's not in beta-eta normal form though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some crucial properties about $\beta$ and $\eta$ reductions that explain the strategies for computing normal forms.

We write $\rightarrow_\beta, \rightarrow_\eta$ for a single step of $\beta$ resp. $\eta$, $\rightarrow^*_{\beta},\rightarrow^*_\eta$ for 0 or more steps, and $\rightarrow^{\mathrm{hd}}_\beta$ for *head* $\beta$-reductions.

> Lemma 1: If $t\rightarrow^*_\beta t'\rightarrow^{\mathrm{hd}}_\beta t''$, then there is some $u$ such that
>   $$ t\rightarrow^{\mathrm{hd}}_\beta u\rightarrow^*_\beta t''$$

So head reduction can always be done right up front, and they always must happen, i.e. they can never "disappear" after a (non-head) $\beta$ reduction. A more subtle result (that relies on this one) is that if there *is* a normal form, then starting with the head reductions is a complete *strategy* to find it.

> Lemma 2: If $t\rightarrow_\eta t' \rightarrow^*_\beta t''$ then there is some $u$ such that
>   $$ t\rightarrow^*_\beta u\rightarrow^*_\eta t''$$

That is, $\eta$ reductions can be "postponed", though they may disappear, e.g. as in $(\lambda x. t\ x)\ u$.

Finally:

> Lemma 3: if $t$ is a $\beta$ normal form, and $t\rightarrow_\eta t'$, then $t'$ is also a $\beta$ normal form.

These 2 lemmas imply that it never hurts to push all the $\eta$ reductions to the very end. So simply adding to the $\beta$ normalization strategy: "And then $\eta$ normalize" is a strategy for finding $\beta\eta$ normal forms.

Answer (score 3):

$\eta$ conversion is not a mean to reduce a term to $\beta$-normal form, but a tool to show equivalence regarding the (future) application; to express that 2 terms “are the same function”; that they will reduce to the same term when applied to arbitrary term(s).

If you want to also do $\eta$ conversions, you can do it anytime because you still have the same term (application-wise) after performing it. Having $\eta$ conversion in the theory will not enrich nor deplete the theory regarding existence of $\beta$($\eta$)-normal forms.